# Suggestions for validation part in crud app using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a crud app using reactjs. When i try to validate, its not getting validated and not getting any results also. Kindly anyone say some valuable suggestions for validation. i am just a beginner so.

the program is given below

```
  valid= () =>{
    if(document.validation.fn.value==="")
    {
        alert("Enter your first name");
        return false;
    }
    if(document.validation.ln.value==="")
    {
        alert(" Enter your last name ");
        return false;
    }
    if(document.validation.dn.value==="")
    {
        alert("Enter your dob");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
};

return (
    <div>
        <form name="validation" method="POST"  onsubmit="return valid()">
            Fname:  <input
            name="fn"
            className={this.props.className}
            onChange={this._handleChange}
            onKeyDown={this._handleKeyDown}
            placeholder="First Name"
            value={this.state.fname}

        />
            Lname:   <input
            name="ln"
            className={this.props.className}
            onChange={this._handleChange1}
            onKeyDown={this._handleKeyDown1}
            placeholder="Last Name"
            value={this.state.lname}

        />
            DOb: <input
            name="dn"
            type="Date"
            className={this.props.className}
            onChange={this._handleChange2}
            onKeyDown={this._handleKeyDown2}
            placeholder="DOB"
            value={this.state.dob}

        />
        </form>
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check my example based on your code: https://codesandbox.io/s/v3qwvyxmql

The main idea is using local state as temporary location for saving data and validation method should use the local state for validating

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      fname: "first name",
      lname: "last name",
      dob: "dob"
    };
  }

  valid() {
    const { fname, lname, dob } = this.state;

    if (fname === "") {
      alert("Enter your first name");
      return false;
    }
    if (lname === "") {
      alert(" Enter your last name ");
      return false;
    }
    if (dob === "") {
      alert("Enter your dob");
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

  handleChange = (e, name) => {
    this.setState({
      [name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!this.valid()) return false;

    console.log("Valid");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          Fname:{" "}
          <input
            name="fn"
            type="text"
            onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, "fname")}
            placeholder="First Name"
            value={this.state.fname}
          />
          Lname:{" "}
          <input
            name="ln"
            type="text"
            onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, "lname")}
            placeholder="Last Name"
            value={this.state.lname}
          />
          DOb:{" "}
          <input
            name="dn"
            type="text"
            onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, "dob")}
            placeholder="DOB"
            value={this.state.dob}
          />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```